# QGIS display on high resolution screens

Tags: qgis

I recently changed over to a laptop with a 3200x1800 resolution screen, and QGIS no longer displays properly. Many items and font are too small and almost unreadable. Slight improvements can be made by changing style, icon size and font under Settings -> Options -> General, however issues still remain, particularly with pop up menus like attribute tables, etc.

Surely there are many users now with screens >1920x1080 resolution, experiencing similar problems?

I have read this question: [Making icons and text larger on high resolution screen for QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163414/making-icons-and-text-larger-on-high-resolution-screen-for-qgis/193075#193075)

And tried this solution: http://www.danantonielli.com/adobe-app-scaling-on-high-dpi-displays-fix/

It does not work for me. Are there any fixes? I'm finding this a major problem (particularly working from a 13" screen).

Edit: picture uploaded. You can see the inconsistency between the sizing of each element. The drop down plus symbols next to the layers can barely be seen let alone clicked accurately, ditto some of the other icons. Similar issues occur with pop up menus

[image]

Comment: You can change your laptop screen resolution to suboptimal (like 1920x1080) within Windows (assuming you're on Windows, other OS's would have similar capability but I'm not sure how they work).

Comment: Thanks Michael. I'm using Windows. I tried changing the resolution under display settings but it really made little to no difference. I'll edit the original post with some screenshots so people can see just how much of an issue this is

Answer (score 5):

It's an ongoing process to update the whole user interface to be compatible with hidpi screens. Basically it boils down to revisiting each icon which is not adapted and redo it. The last couple of days many icons have been updated.

Please try a recent nightly build (master version, to become 2.16 soon) and report issues for icons which are still not updated.

## Examples of recent updates

### Export and composer toolbar

[image: Some icons]

Source: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/3219

### Attribute table

[image: The attribute table]

Source: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/3219

Comment: Thanks Matthias, much appreciated.I'm fairly new to QGIS. As far as I can tell, I will have to set myself up with the advanced installation to get the nightly builds, and then report problems here? http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues

The most concerning issues I'm having right now are the size of the cursor (regardless of tool selected) and the size of the style previews for polygons in the layer control. I'll check if these have been updated and submit a report if not. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, you can get the nightlies with the OSGeo4W installer and report issues according to https://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/bugreporting.html