# QGIS, Text size issues

Tags: qgis, popup

I have dealt with this text size issue for awhile and through multiple version, but I cant deal with it anymore, so I thought I would come on here and see if anyone had a fix. In my QGIS the text in the map window and in most pop-up boxes is gigantic:

[image: Screenshot of QGIS window]

Note that the text size for the toolbars is what I would think is normal sized, while the text in the recent projects (behind the VRB pop-up) and the virtual raster builder window is massive in comparison. The text setting in general is set at 10 with icon at the smallest setting of 16. When I change the text size in the general settings it only affects the toolbars not the actual text in the pop-up windows.

I will add that I think it might be related to screen resolution, as my 2 monitors have a lower resolution then my laptop display...but my laptop display is off since I'm docked and only using the external monitors. and I haven't been able to fix it by playing with my display settings.

How can I tame the size of the text so I can actually see all of what is displayed?

Answer (score 4):

A co-worker found a solution on here from a previous screen resolution issue. I just had to go to my QGIS executable and adjust the DPI settings which you can view in this question:

[Making icons and text larger on high resolution screen for QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163414/making-icons-and-text-larger-on-high-resolution-screen-for-qgis)

All better now:
[image]